# Move file after successful ftp transfer using Java DSL

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

I've defined a flow using spring-integration java dsl to ftp transfer a file, handle it, then transfer it back in an "archive" dir, and at last move it in a local archive dir.
Which is something "quite easy" as:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ftpInboundFlow() {
    if (ftpProperties.getEnabled() == false) {
        return null;
    }
    logger.trace("Starting ftp flow");
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(source -> source.ftp(ftpSessionFactory()).deleteRemoteFiles(true).preserveTimestamp(true)
                    .filter(compositeWithAcceptOnceFilter())                        .remoteDirectory(ftpProperties.getRemoteDirectory())
                    .localDirectory(new File(ftpProperties.getLocalDirectory())).autoCreateLocalDirectory(true),
            consumer -> consumer.id("ftpInboundAdapter")) /* Fine from() */
            .handle(new GenericHandler<File>() {

                @Override
                @Transactional
                public Object handle(File payload, Map<String, Object> headers) {
                    logger.debug("Data arrived {} {}", payload, payload.getClass().getName());
                    return payload;
                }

            }) /* Fine GenericHandler */
            .handleWithAdapter(a -> a.ftp(ftpSessionFactory())
                    .remoteDirectory(ftpProperties.getRemoteArchiveDirectory()).autoCreateDirectory(true))              
            .get();
}
```

If I append

```
.handleWithAdapter(a -> a.file("'" + ftpProperties.getLocalArchiveDirectory() + "'")
.autoCreateDirectory(true).deleteSourceFiles(true))
```

after the ftp adapter configuration the bean initializer replies with the following error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: The 'currentComponent' (org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler@80bfa9d) is a one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel'. This is the end of the integration flow.
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround I refactored my code in giving up with the file adapter:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ftpInboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(source -> source.ftp(ftpSessionFactory()).deleteRemoteFiles(true).preserveTimestamp(true)
                .filter(compositeWithAcceptOnceFilter())                        .remoteDirectory(ftpProperties.getRemoteDirectory())
                .localDirectory(new File(ftpProperties.getLocalDirectory())).autoCreateLocalDirectory(true),
        consumer -> consumer.id("ftpInboundAdapter")) /* Fine from() */
        .handle(new GenericHandler<File>() {

            @Override
            @Transactional
            public Object handle(File payload, Map<String, Object> headers) {
                logger.debug("Data arrived {} {}", payload, payload.getClass().getName());
                /* handle file content here ... */
                /* ... then move it to archive */
                File dstFile = new File("archive", payload);
                FileUtils.moveFile(payload, dstFile);
                return dstFile;
            }

        }) /* Fine GenericHandler */
        /* Archive the remote file */
        .handleWithAdapter(a -> a.ftp(ftpSessionFactory())
                .remoteDirectory(ftpProperties.getRemoteArchiveDirectory()).autoCreateDirectory(true))              
        .get();
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the solution.You made my day

Comment: @lrkwz I am new to DSL thing. I doing similar thing. I need you to xmplain me what "ftpInboundAdpert" is ( is it of type Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec> ). Second how do you trigger this to manually work maybe through external API call ( separate Service). I am using sftp but similar situation

Comment: @DanHunex I guess you can trigger it dropping a file in your (s)ftp directory; if you are doing test automation I would suggest you to build your test environment using docker-compose in order to have all the services easily controllable.

Answer (score 2):

With the XML configuration we have a convention for one-way component like `adapter`, e.g. `<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>` or `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>`. For the Java DSL we use the convention like `Gateway` suffix for the factory methods which produces `request/reply` endpoint. Otherwise it is one way, like yours `a.ftp(ftpSessionFactory())`.

From other side with the XML configuration we don't have any choice to go ahead with downstream flow definition because there is no `output-channel` on the `<outbound-channel-adapter>`.

With the Java DSL we don't have so much choice to prevent such a error like your. But I did there so comprehensive exception message which should follow you to the different way for your flow definition.

And the answer for you is `.publishSubscribeChannel()`, when you can subscribe several endpoints to it to accept the same message to make different logic for it.

Please, find my [article](https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/25/spring-integration-java-dsl-line-by-line-tutorial) where I explain most of SI Java DSL features line by line.

Comment: publish/subscribe might not always be appropriate i.e. in my scenario I'd like to move files to the local archive folder only upon successful upload over SFTP (further more I need to upload a marker file per destination requirement); if I use pub/sub then in case of outage of SFTP destination endpoint - file will be moved to the local archive folder, while upload won't happen. I'm using Advice from SFTP adapter to set success channel which is routing message for post-processing stuff. Pls advise if there is a better way of doing that.