# Need to process multiple files in parallel in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I have a SFTP directory and reading files and sending the files for further processing to a ServiceActivator.At any point I need to process them parallely using the handler.

Here is my SPring Integration java DSL flow.

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(getSftpSessionFactory())
                        .temporaryFileSuffix("COPY")
                        .localDirectory(directory)
                        .deleteRemoteFiles(false)
                        .preserveTimestamp(true)
                        .remoteDirectory("remoteDir"))
                        .patternFilter("*.txt")), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(500).maxMessagesPerPoll(5)))
                        .handle("mybean", "myMethod")
                        .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File("success")))         
                        .deleteSourceFiles(true)
                        .autoCreateDirectory(true))
                        .get();
```

Update:Here is my ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
@Bean(name = "executor")
public Executor getExecutor()
{
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(20);          
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Sftp.inboundAdapter()` (`SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource`) returns remote files one by one anyway. First of all it synchronizes them to the local directory and only after that poll them for message processing as `File` payload.

To process them in parallel that would be just enough to add a `taskExecutor` to your `e.poller()` definition and all those `maxMessagesPerPoll(5)` will be distributed to different threads.

Comment: I did try that option I got an exception .    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1@41c6ed7a rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@53ee0cd5[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 4, queued tasks = 20, completed tasks = 1]   Also the execution is very slow.Slower than single thread.

Comment: That's not a problem of `TaskExecutor`. Your handler is somehow slow, maybe blocked somewhere. From other side you always can use `CallerRunsPolicy` instead of the default `AbortPolicy`.

Comment: Where do we add CallerRunsPolicy

Comment: To the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler()`

Comment: I tried with CallerRuns but still it's slow. I have doubt over my method. I will check that also will these lines block the thread? handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File("success"))) .deleteSourceFiles(true)

Comment: Didn't want to raise a new question but if needed will do it.Wanted to know how to move the file in the SFTP server from one folder to another folder?

Comment: Consider to use `MV` command of the `<int-sftp:outbound-gateway>`.

Comment: .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(getSftpSessionFactory(),Command.MV,?))   what is the last String for?

Comment: A SpEL expression for the `source` file path. See Reference Manual for more info: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway. The Java DSL is fully based on those options. Don't forget the `renameExpression` option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156737/moving-processed-files-in-remote-sftp-using-java-dsl for those of you who will read this thread in future,this link question has the answer.

Comment: I ended up using this solution and highly recommend anyone to use this solution.Its too good http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31819189/move-file-after-successful-ftp-transfer-using-java-dsl

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, assigning the taskExecutor to the channel did the trick.
Here is the code I used for a really simple application that polls a folder and processes the files. Files are handled in parallel, even if I assign only one thread to the poller.

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringIntegrationDemoApplication {

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    SpringApplication.run( SpringIntegrationDemoApplication.class, args );
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow fileReadingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from( Files.inboundAdapter( new File( "/tmp/in" ) ).patternFilter( "*.txt" ),
               e ->
                   e.poller( Pollers.fixedDelay( 10000 )
//                               .taskExecutor( Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 1 ) )
                                 .maxMessagesPerPoll( 100 )
                   ) )
        .channel( MessageChannels.executor( Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 100 ) ) )
        .handle( "myFileHandler", "handleMessage" )
        .get();
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageHandler myFileHandler() {
    return message -> {
      try {
        log.info( "START" + message.getPayload() );
        Thread.sleep( 2000 );
        log.info( "STOP" + message.getPayload() );
      }
      catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    };
  }
}
```